# Performance issues processing large files in SSIS

Tags: ssis

We currently process files containing millions of records from different customers using SSIS and SQL Server.

Once these files are received, they are loaded into the database and different kinds of joins are performed to extract and merge data from didfferent data sources.

Once the data is massaged, the final output data is extracted to a file and uploaded to FTP.

We are implementing the above logic using SSIS and on average it takes 3 minutes per seller's file. This is a lot of time and we would like to process each seller's file within a minute. All the SPs and components within the SSIS package are already tuned.

We are currently processing the files serially which is one of the reasons we are facing performance issues. However, since there is no budget to accrue additional hardware at this time, we are unable to process the seller's files in parallel as it will lead to resource crunch on the server. My question is what else can we do to expedite the processing time of the files without procuring additional hardware ? We are open to try new technologies.

Comment: What do your control + data flows look like? What data types do you deal with? Do you know where the bottleneck is: disk, cpu, memory, network?

Comment: I would; remove your transformations from SSIS, bulk import files to PERMANENT (not temp) tables, use SQL (s procs) to transform the data, dump the transformed data to files, truncate the tables. Use SSIS (as the controller ) to call the bulk import/exec sp/dump data. Actually... you dont need SSIS if only dealing with flat files, it all can be done in T-SQL in a agent job.